# Audio Play Error in Corona Sdk

Tags: audio, lua, runtime-error, coronasdk

I´m with this error in my simulator:

main.lua:24: audio.loadSound() failed to create sound '1.wav'

The sound is correctly wirte

here´s my code:

[image: code]

(i already change the name and local of my sound and didn´t work)

and i have this other code here:

[image: code 2]

and he´s working perfectly

Can You Help Me pls?

(I´m Brazilian so sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- Cross-platform .wav files must be 16-bit uncompressed,
- audio.loadSound() — loads an entire sound into memory. It should be used for shorter audio files that may be used repeatedly throughout the app,
- read more https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/audioSystem/index.html
- check localization of 1.wav file

Hope this help
ldurniat

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not specify the correct path? For example if it was in the "Sounds" folder you would need:

```
x = audio.loadSound("Sounds/1.wav")
```